# Angular js - slide views but not home page - ng-animate

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, slide, ng-animate

i'm using **ng-animate** to slide the app views, so each route slides own view , this is my simple code:

*html:*

```
<div ng-view ng-animate class="slide"></div>
```

*css:*

```
/*Animations*/
.slide{
  left:0;
}
.slide.ng-enter{
  transition:0.15s linear all;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:inherit;
  left:-100%;
  height:inherit;
}
.slide.ng-leave{
  transition:0.15s linear all;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:9999;
  right:0;
}
.slide.ng-leave-active{
  transition:0.15s linear all;
  position:fixed;
  right:-100%;
  left:100%;
}
.slide.ng-enter-active{
  transition:0.15s linear all;
  left:0;
  position:relative;
}
```

Now, i'm wondering , **`is there anyway to exclude the home page (main "/" route) from sliding?`**

In other terms: **Any way to exclude a route from ng-animate?**

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @PavelNikolov nope still searching for a good solution

Comment: I don't think `ng-animate` will do anything here, there is no information about `ng-animate` directive in official document. Also I updated my answer to reflect the newest request from @sbaaaang.

Comment: Hey there sorry i'm really newbie on angular and my question was asking for a best practice i gave +1 to all of you but i'm in trouble on which answer to accept cause IMO these are all good solutions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what `ng-class` is for.

You can set a application-wide variable $rootScope.path whenever path changes.

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
    $rootScope.path = $location.path();
  });
});
```

Then, you decide to set your animation class by that variable

If you want to set class `slide` only if path is not `/`, do like this

```
<div ng-view ng-class="{slide: path !== '/' }"></div>
```

By doing this way, you don't need to touch any of your controller.

Full demo is here, http://plnkr.co/edit/rmu8oc7ycKzRaA2zv5JN?p=preview

By the way, this uses currant angularJS version, 1.2.7

------- Edit (animate after visit main page) ------

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
    if (!$location.path().match(/^\/?$/) && !$rootScope.mainVisitedOnce) {
      $rootScope.mainVisitedOnce = true;
    }
  });
});
```

and

```
<div ng-view ng-class="{slide: mainVisitedOnce }"></div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/QpDFkdKH1kk6ZXy07G5X?p=preview

Comment: i really like your sollution, just do you think it's possible to to the exact same thing but only on first app load? i mean only 1 time , only when app is opened for the first time...

Comment: Yes, but that was not a part of your question which not to slide when app loads

Comment: I edited the answer not to animate when app loads. so, please edit your question accordingly so that viewers can see answers are following your question.

Comment: Hey there sorry i'm really newbie on angular and my question was asking for a best practice i gave +1 to all of you but i'm in trouble on which answer to accept cause IMO these are all good solutions

Answer (score 4):

#### Demo http://plnkr.co/edit/sMUM48?p=preview

#### Explain

No need to create separate controller, directive or change any business logic. Just use `.animation` method to add conditional animation to `.slide`.

Listen to `$routeChangeSuccess` event on `$rootScope`. This is event will be triggered before animation start, so you have time to set `toRoot` and `fromRoot` flag accordingly. If target view is not a **"/" view**, a `enable-animation` class will be added to `ng-view` element, so css transition defined will be performed.

If target view if a **"/" view**, no animation will be performed.

HTML

```
<ng-view class="slide"></ng-view>
```

CSS

```
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.slide div {
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.slide.enable-animation.ng-enter,
.slide.enable-animation.ng-leave {
  transition: all 10s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slide.enable-animation.ng-enter {
  left: -100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.slide.enable-animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
.slide.enable-animation.ng-leave {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.slide.enable-animation.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  left: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

JavaScript

```
app.animation('.slide', function($rootScope, $animate) {

  var toRoot = false;
  var fromRoot = false;

  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, old) {
    toRoot = (current.$$route.originalPath === '/');
    fromRoot = (old.$$route.originalPath === '/');
  });

  return {
    enter: function(element, done) {
      if (!toRoot) {
        element.addClass('enable-animation');
      }
      done();
    },

    leave: function(element, done) {
      if (!fromRoot) {
        element.addClass('enable-animation');
        done();
      } else {
        // set 1000ms timeout to sync with CSS animation
        // otherwise leaving ng-view element will be removed before entering ng-view is in position
        setTimeout(done, 1000);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

## Update 1

If you just want to exclude a route only when the first time app loads, you basically don't have to do anything, just define your css animation like normal. The first loaded route won't trigger any animation.

#### Demo http://plnkr.co/edit/uRZyZA?p=preview

Comment: Hey there sorry i'm really newbie on angular and my question was asking for a best practice i gave +1 to all of you but i'm in trouble on which answer to accept cause IMO these are all good solutions

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from @allenhwkim, get path in your rootScope.

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
    $rootScope.path = $location.path();
  });
});
```

Then have this as your element:

```
<div ng-view ng-animate ng-class="{slide: path !== '/' }"></div>
```

`.slide` will be added to your container element when the path being loaded *isn't* `/`.

[Here's a working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YhGpGCVEszI0VJOsuwHx?p=preview).

Comment: Can you provide a working plnkr, because I didn't see `ng-animate` directive in official documentation.

Comment: I seem to have been thinking about Angular 1.1.X while writing my answer — a mistake. I've updated my answer to suit Angular 1.2.9.

Comment: Since my solution involved what @allenhwkim originally did, I'm upvoting his answer.

Comment: Hey there sorry i'm really newbie on angular and my question was asking for a best practice i gave +1 to all of you but i'm in trouble on which answer to accept cause IMO these are all good solutions

Comment: I think it should go to allenhwkim, because my solution ended up being the one he originally posted, which, I think, is the most elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply add a root class like `class="not-animated"` and `class="animated"` to the controllers you don't want or want to be animated?
In this way you could use the `.not-animated` and `.animated` class to play with your animation in different controllers.

You can set your controller like this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-class='isAnimated'>
  <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl" ng-class='isAnimated'>Foo</div>
  <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl" ng-class='isAnimated'>Bar</div>
</body>

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.isAnimated = 'not-animated';
});

app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.isAnimated = 'animated';
});
```

This will result in:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-class="isAnimated" class="ng-scope not-animated">
    <p class="ng-binding">Hello World!</p>
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl" ng-class="isAnimated" class="ng-scope not-animated">Foo</div>
    <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl" ng-class="isAnimated" class="ng-scope animated">Bar</div>   
</body>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y5R9TsToNMLnnxfpGbDB?p=preview)

Comment: d'you mean creating a crontoller for the main animated div?

Comment: I set up a quick plunker to demonstrate what I mean. Of course you don't need to apply it everywhere, you could set it up just where you need it.

Comment: You could add the ng-class when you add the animation, but maybe it could be a bit verbose.

Comment: Hey there sorry i'm really newbie on angular and my question was asking for a best practice i gave +1 to all of you but i'm in trouble on which answer to accept cause IMO these are all good solutions

Answer (score 1):

You can build a controller that listens for route changes and sets a class accordingly. You will then be able to target the correct animation using CSS.

```
<body ng-controller="TranisitionCtrl" ng-class="currentRoute">
  <div ng-view ng-animate></div>
</body>

app.controller('TranisitionCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(ev, next, current) { 
    $scope.currentRoute = current.name;
  });
});
```

Please note $routeChangeStart has been changed to $locationChangeStart for more recent versions of angular.

I've answered another similar question here [Two different animations for route changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104180/two-different-animations-for-route-changes/20329683#20329683)

Comment: Hey there sorry i'm really newbie on angular and my question was asking for a best practice i gave +1 to all of you but i'm in trouble on which answer to accept cause IMO these are all good solutions

Comment: Would you elaborate on `$routeChangeStart` being changed to `$locationChangeStart` in recent Angular? I was under the impression they handle different parts of the logic - location event being fired for an URL change while route event for a different view based on that location, though they're not necessarily inclusive under all circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

One way to exclude a specific route from the animation is to use a JS animation wrapper that will take over setting of the animation class for your `ng-view`.  You need one additional class to handle the non-animated `ng-leave` when you are going back to the non-animated route.

Here is a sample JS wrapper that check for a custom `animate` attribute in your route to decide if a route is animated or not:

```
app.animation('.slider', function($log, $route) {
  return {
    //call done when the animation is over
    enter : function(element, done) {
      if ($route.current.animate) {
        element.addClass("slide ng-enter");
      }
      done();
    },
    leave : function(element, done) {
      if ($route.current.animate) {
        element.addClass("slide ng-leave");
      } else {
        // Need to add non-animated version of ng-leave
        element.addClass("slide ng-leave-noanimation");
      }
      done();
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the working plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ldCy9Cfz2lJWNuLzDIbp?p=preview

Comment: Hey there sorry i'm really newbie on angular and my question was asking for a best practice i gave +1 to all of you but i'm in trouble on which answer to accept cause IMO these are all good solutions

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand you, what you want is, that no animation happens if the user hits your site. But after that the animations should happen all the time. This is the shortest solution i know:

Use the module `run` method to disable all animations:

```
app.run(function($animate){
    $animate.enabled(false);
});
```

In your controller that is bound to `/` reenable the animations, but delayed for one digest cycle:

```
.controller('rootController', function($timeout, $animate){
    $timeout(function(){
        $animate.enabled(true);
    });
})
```

Comment: Hey there sorry i'm really newbie on angular and my question was asking for a best practice i gave +1 to all of you but i'm in trouble on which answer to accept cause IMO these are all good solutions